# We were unable to update QuickSight permissions for AWS resources

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-athena, amazon-quicksight

We were unable to update QuickSight permissions for AWS resources. Either you are not authorized to edit QuickSight permissions on AWS resources, or the QuickSight permissions were changed using the IAM console and are therefore no longer updateable through QuickSight.

Comment: Hi Waqar, what is your question? Are you asking what to do if you see this error message?

Answer (score 0):

When I click on Manage Quicksight on top right corner in AWS Quicksight then going to security and permission Tab then ADD or Remove Tab when i add S3 bucket then Amazon S3 . When I update then I get the above error. Now Successfully I sort out the issue. Just Going to AWS IAM Policies Tab filter Quicksight. you got different polices related to quicksight like AWSQuickSightS3Policy just updated it and finally the issue is resolved.Thanks